# Get storeId from product

Tags: product, store-view

How can I get the store ID from a product instance ?

I have tried: `$product->getStoreId();`

but it don't works.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a `getStoreIds()` method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load([item_id]);
$storeIds = $_product->getStoreIds();
```